# Tag synonym request: [window-placement] -> [window-managment]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

The two tags [window-placement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window-placement) and [window-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window-management) are essentially synonyms. Since it has only been used 7 times, [window-placement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window-placement) should probably be deleted, especially since the description for [window-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window-management) (used 82 times) is "the placement of application windows." I guess [window-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window-management) could use a better description since it's more than just placement, but it would certainly include placement.

Comment: Definitely they would need to be defined (better, at all) to know exactly what to do.. or if these tags are necessary.